# How do I match multiple atoms in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, match

How do I do the below, for example

```
A = atom_a,  
case A of  
 atom_b or atom_c ->   
      %do something here;  
 atom a ->  
      %do something else!  
end.
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use guards:

```
A = 'atom_a',
case A of
  B when B =:= 'atom_b'; B =:= 'atom_c' ->   
    %do something here;  
  'atom_a' ->  
    %do something else!  
end.
```

Answer (score 11):

Try the following:

```
case is_special_atom(A) of
    true ->
        %do something here;
    false ->
         %do something else!
end.

is_special_atom(atom_b) -> true;
is_special_atom(atom_c) -> true;
is_special_atom(_) -> false.
```

Comment: This *factoring* solution is usually an excellent way of doing it. I've seen it used where the return value is far more complex than a `boolean()` though. Use an auxiliary function to analyze the outcome and then case on this outcome.